# Is there an Illustrator version of updating linked objects/assets like you can with smart objects in Photoshop in multiple artboards?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I'm attempting to create a shorter process/template for creating display banners that involve text/imagery without having to manually update each artboard. I use both Photoshop and Illustrator, but unlike Illustrator, Photoshop has smart objects that automatically update.

Does anyone know of a way to update any graphics, text, etc on multiple artboards in Illustrator that are linked? I've tried updating assets in the cc library but it only updates within the library itself, not placed objects. It'd be incredibly insightful if anyone has a better process for creating mass amounts of digital banners that can be updated more efficiently!

Comment: Not certain I understand. Anything which is **linked** in an Illustrator file, i.e. shows in the Link panel, should update upon opening the AI file, or present a warning informing that the link has changed and ask if you want to update it.

Comment: The Adobe Illustrator always update a linked file when we edit it and switch back to Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for your needs is libraries. Just create your item/asset and then use the option called "Place Linked".

All changes that you'll make in the item will update automatically in all documents with this item. I've just tested this case.

PS. I cannot add comments to post so I've added an answer.